# Can't connect kibana to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I installed kibana version 8.10.4 but when i try kibana.bat i get

Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: index_not_found_exception
Root causes:
index_not_found_exception: no such index [.kibana]

This is the only uncommented part in elasticsearch.yml file:

## Enable security features

xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

## Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents

xpack.security.http.ssl:
enabled: false
keystore.path: certs/http.p12

## Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
enabled: true
verification_mode: certificate
keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
truststore.path: certs/transport.p12

## Create a new cluster with the current node only

## Additional nodes can still join the cluster later

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["AKTAK-93NA12UMF"]

## Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere

## Connections are encrypted and require user authentication

http.host: 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

To start Kibana, as error message said we need .kibana file. This file consists of kibana internal data such as dashboards, saved visualizations. Did you start elasticsearch, before you start kibana?